# push software changes to different client sites

Tags: open-source, web-apps, web-development, continuous-integration

The company I work for is building a web application. That application has change/improvement every week or so.

For any release we are doing, we put the amended/additional files into the clients FTP and send them an email, detailing the client where to put the files.

Is there a software that can automate this task and help us push the new files, directly into the client server, without the client doing anything?

Thanks

PS: Our software is built with .net, mostly and IIS as the web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try the official Web deploy system from Microsoft? Here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

Comment: Hi @juanga-covas, thanks. wouid it work with servers installed on the client's side e.g within a different netwrok...?

Comment: Seems that "you can use Visual Studio to create installation packages to automate the deployment" [...] One option is to "create Web Deployment setup packages within VS, and publish them to remote (Windows) servers that have the Web Deploy service installed and enabled" [...] and "also you can package your ASP.NET Web Application into a .zip based deployment package file that Web Deploy understands. You can then hand-off the deployment package file to someone who can deploy it either via the IIS Admin Tool, or via a command-line/powershell script [...]

Do your research, I think should work

Comment: I need to have a look. many thanks @juanga-covas